# Bash ./ get subset with length of 8 chars

Tags: bash

I have the following input:

```
line="before,myinput1,after"
```

`myinput1` can be also first or last. for example: `line="myinput1,after"` or `line="before,myinput1"`

Im trying to get only the myinput1 value (which can be changed). tried this:

```
line | grep -o -E ',.{0,7}.,'
```

which its returned the following value: `,myinput1,`. The issue its not working if the value is first or last because the missing `,`.

is there any other way to do that?

Comment: If the input is `somevalue,othervalue`, which one do you want? I.e. how do you tell whether it's after or before?

Comment: Can you give us more information on what exactly you want to extract? The title sounds like you want to extract values with exactly 8 chars. The regex allows values with 1-8 chars. So `before,` and `,after` would also match.

Comment: This pattern will give you any set of characters which have commas before and behind, which would match ,1234567,` but also `,123,` or `,123,567,` or even `,,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using grep, a regex for 8 characters (assuming you only want an 8 character string) is  `\w{8}`. Using OR operators `|` the three cases needed (start of line, end of line and somewhere in the middle of the line) can be expressed as:

`egrep -o ',\w{8},|^\w{8},|,\w{8}$'`

Comment: Or `(^|,)\w{8}(,|$)`. However, I would replace `\w` by `[^,]` such that fields can contain spaces and other non-word characters.

Answer (score 0):

To catch fields of 8 characters in a comma delimited string, you can use `awk`:

```
awk -v RS=, 'length()==8' <<< "$line"
```

`RS` sets the record separator to the comma `,`.

awk `length()` function gives the size of the current record.

Answer (score 0):

With bash :

```
(IFS=',';set -- $line;for i;do [ ${#i} -eq 8 ] && echo $i ;done)
```